# Way to send Computer audio wirelessly (wifi or bluetooth) to iOS device to be heard on its speakers?

Tags: ios, wifi, audio, bluetooth

> Inspired by this question over on Ask Ubuntu:
>
> [A method to send Ubuntu's (16.04) audio over WiFi to iOS (10.2) device?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/877927/a-method-to-send-ubuntus-16-04-audio-over-wifi-to-ios-10-2-device)

Is there a way to stream audio from another computer (whether it's Linux, Mac, or Windows) to an iOS device (iPhone, iPad, etc.) such that the audio can play over the iOS device?

I know there are solutions for Android or such, but was curious if there's a solution or method to do this with iOS devices.

Answer (score 1):

You can buy a bluetooth to audio jack adapter:

[https://www.amazon.com/Wireless-Bluetooth-Stereo-Adapter-Transmitter/dp/B00RHKYX7W](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00RHKYX7W)

This way you should be able to use it as an amplifier using Garage Band amp on your iPhone.

It should work just like so:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RkL0bIx-ESk